# Python HTTPS Requests: Get a file from GCP and send it to another location?

Tags: python, api, google-cloud-platform, https

I have a script that scans a local folder and uploads some of the files to an SQL Server through a POST request. I would love to modify it to take files from a GCP bucket instead of from local storage. However I have no experience with GCP and I am having difficulty finding documentation supporting what I am trying to do. I have a few questions for anyone who has tried anything like this before:

1. Is a GET request the best way to copy GCP bucket files into a different location? I.e Is there a way to put my script directly into GCP and just use the POST request I already have, referencing the bucket instead of a folder?
2. If a GET request is the best way, does anyone know of a good resource to learn about HTTPS requests with GCP? (Not sure how to create the GET request/ what information Google would need).
3. After my GET request (if this is the best way), do the files necessarily have to download to my computer before the POST request to the SQL server OR is there any way to send the files to upload without having to download them?

Comment: you need to use google python api and get file from gcp bucket...similr to boto3 from aws,.\

Comment: Thanks @vks ! Do you know if it is possible to send the gcp file somewhere else without downloading it first?

Comment: Google Cloud has excellent documentation and examples in Python. Start at the beginning and learn the Cloud Storage service before attempting your project. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-python

Comment: Thanks @JohnHanley (edit: oops I missed the link in your comment) thanks so much I will start reading!

Comment: @Kate if the file is small you can read and keep in memory

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace your local storage by Cloud Storage, you have several things to know

- The most transparent, and if you use a linux compliant OS, is to use [GCSFuse](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse). You will be able to mount a Cloud Storage bucket in a local directory and work as it was a local storage. **HOWEVER**, GCSFuse is a wrapper that transform system call to HTTP calls, latency, feature and performance are absolutely not the same.
- When you search a file on Cloud Storage, you can only search with a prefix, not with a suffix (if you look for special extension such as .sql or .csv, it's not possible).
- You must download the file content locally before sending it to your database. Except if you have a module/extension in your database able to read data from an URL or directly from Cloud Storage (that shouldn't exist).
- [gsutil](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil) is the best tool to handle the Cloud Storage file